# Linux wordpress image upload error on localhost

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, localhost

I tried to write in console this command for all permissions for folder:

```
chmod u+rwxrwxrwx /var/www
```

But I am confused because I got this output:

```
ls -la /var/www
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 Ağu 16 12:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Ağu 16 12:24 ..
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 Ağu 19 04:29 html
```

There is all permission for html folder, or I am wrong? this folder in var/www yes? So it needs another command for special permission this var/www folder like in error?

And I tried a few more ways but I could not fix this error:

```
Could not move uploaded file here: wp-content / uploads.
```

Answer (score 0):

Root is the owner of html/...
You should try to change the owner (esp. for wp-content), so that PHP have the permission to write/move in these folders.